# Convert Chinese Unicode Code Points To Strings Using Python

Tags: python, unicode, cjk

I have a file containing Unicode Code Points for 8105 Chinese characters from [here](http://hanzidb.org/character-list/general-standard) looking similar to

```
U+516D
U+4E03
U+516B
```

I understand these represent the following Chinese characters

```
六 [Chinese character for 'six', Reference http://hanzidb.org/character/%E5%85%AD]
七 [Chinese character for 'seven', Reference http://hanzidb.org/character/%E4%B8%83]
八 [Chinese character for 'eight', Reference http://hanzidb.org/character/%E5%85%AB]
```

How to convert the file containing strings `U+516D`, `U+4E03`, `U+516B` to the corresponding Chinese characters using Python 3?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def get_character(string):
    return chr(int(string[2:], 16))
```

```
>>> get_character("U+4E03")
'七'
>>> get_character("U+516D")
'六'
>>> get_character("U+4E03")
'七'
>>> get_character("U+516B")
'八'
```

This is is the simplest method I know of, note it doesn't check the proper format, just chops off the first 2 characters assuming `U+`

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will convert text in `U+hhhh`format (4-6 hexadecimal characters) into its corresponding Unicode code point:

```
import re

s = 'U+516D U+4E03 U+516B'

s = re.sub(r'U\+([0-9A-F]{4,6})',lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1),16)),s)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
六 七 八
```